# attach jquery handler to modal after it has been loaded

Tags: jquery

I am loading a modal on click of #show-delete.  Inside that modal (which is a remote page) I want to attach a handler for on click of #delete-user.  This handler is not working at all and the button does nothing.

If I place the deleteAccount function inside the actual modal page (m_delete_user.php) the handler works, but for sake of ease and other operations I would like to keep these in index.php.

**inside index.php :**

```
// show delete user modal
var showDelete = function() {
    $('#show-delete').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var username = $form.find("select[name=account_username]").val();

        //open the modal with the username value
        $('#modal-ajax').load('/spc_admin/modals/m_delete_user.php?username='+username);
        $('#modal-ajax').modal('show');

        // initialize the button handler
        deleteAccount();                
    });
}

// delete user (modal delete button)
var deleteAccount = function() {
    $('#delete-user').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/spc_admin/process/p_delete_user.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.success) {

... and continued
```

Comment: Why are you using `var showDelete = function() ` instead of `function showDelete()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the `.load()` operation is complete because it's asynchronous.  You can do that using the completion function passed to `.load()` and trigger the installation of your deleteAccount handlers with the completion function.

```
// delete user (modal delete button)
var deleteAccount = function() {
    $('#delete-user').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/spc_admin/process/p_delete_user.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.success) {

... and continued

// show delete user modal
var showDelete = function() {
    $('#show-delete').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var username = $form.find("select[name=account_username]").val();

        //open the modal with the username value
        // ==> deleteAccount added as a completion function here
        $('#modal-ajax').load('/spc_admin/modals/m_delete_user.php?username='+username, deleteAccount);
        $('#modal-ajax').modal('show');

    });
}
```